# How to move S3 data to one partition level up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Let's say I have a table in the path

```
s3:bucketname/tablename/month/day/deviceid
```

I want to move all files to `s3:bucketname/tablename/month/day/`. In other words, I want to ignore the last partition.

Note that there are already data in the path `s3:bucketname/tablename/month/day/`

Can I use `aws s3` to achieve this?

I have more than 100K files so I cannot do this manually.

Comment: Are they the _actual_ names of the directories, or would they really be something like `s3://bucketname/tablename/month=01/day=23/`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [the AWS console on the web](https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/). Open the source folder (`deviceid`), select all its contents by the checkbox to the left on Name.

[image: You can select all files with a single click]

Then select Actions → Copy.

[image]

Open the destination folder (`day`), click Actions → Paste. Confirm the operation.

[image]

Once the operation has finished successfully, you can delete the source folder with all its contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways.

If you are not familiar with the aws cli, then go to the console, select all the files, cut and paste on the desired directory. However, this is very time consuming and inefficient task.

I recommend the aws cli for S3. You can find some sample commands [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html).